# Is there a Guix equivalent of nix-shell shebangs?

Tags: scripting, shebang, guix

I want to write a script which executes within a specific `guix shell` environment.  I'm hoping there's an equivalent version of the [`nix-shell` shebang](https://nixos.wiki/wiki/Nix-shell_shebang).  For example, it would be cool to write something similar to the following:

```bash
#!guix shell
#!--manifest=manifest.scm bash

# ... commands ...
```

As a workaround, it may be sufficient to "source" the search paths of evaluating `guix shell`, e.g.:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

eval "$(guix shell --manifest=manifest.scm --search-paths)"

# ... commands ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use this shebang, which allows for any packaged interpreter:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env -S guix shell [--pure] [-m manifest.scm] [packages...] -- bash
```

Answer (score 1):

Evaluating the search paths from `guix shell` seems to be an effective alternative.  It's, perhaps, not as cute as `#!nix-shell`.  But perhaps that's a feature.

That is, at the top of the file, add the following line, assuming the manifest.scm file exists within the same directory:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
eval "$(guix shell --manifest=manifest.scm --search-paths)"

# ...
```

Additionally, the `--pure` option can be added to ensure the script is self-contained.

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
eval "$(guix shell --pure --manifest.scm --search-paths)"

# ...
```

If the script exists within a [shell authorized directory](https://guix.gnu.org/manual/devel/en/html_node/Invoking-guix-shell.html), then the following will work:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

eval "$(guix shell --search-paths)"

# ...
```

Without a manifest also works:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
eval "$(guix shell --pure python-wrapper python-numpy --search-paths)"

exec python wrapped-python-script.py "$@"
```

However, what this approach does not support, which the `nix-shell` variant does, is using the shebang to create an environment for a different interpreter.  For example, with `nix-shell` it's possible the script is itself a python file but the magic byte of the shebang creates a nix "profile" for the python file.  For this, the Guix approach would be to use the above to create a wrapper around the script; use `exec` for good process management and fun.